# Batch docker registry manifest deletion: How to list manifests via v2 REST api?

Tags: list, manifest, docker-registry

I would like to delete particular or all manifests in my private docker registry remotely (v2 api) to make it possible images data to be collected by gc. I found this [tool](https://github.com/andrey-pohilko/registry-cli), but it only works with tags. I decided to extend it. I would like to enumerate manifests. Is it possible to get manifests list? I can't find something useful on this.

I checked those and I'm also searching the web, but with no success.

- https://docs.docker.com/registry/spec/api/
- https://docs.docker.com/registry/garbage-collection/

**--UPDATE--**

Either of both results in 404 error of course (I just prefer using `wget`). For

```
https://<registry-origin>/v2/gk-backend/tags/list
```

I got `{"name":"gk-backend","tags":["latest"]}` as I expect. When I try father to get the manifest I have 404. I issue the request by using `wget` like

```
wget --method=HEAD --header="Accept: application/vnd.docker.distribution.manifest.v2+json" --no-check-certificate --http-user user --http-password pass https://<registry-origin>/v2/wjs-wealth/manifests/gk-backend:latest -O-
```

And `curl` also gives me 404

```
curl --header "Accept: application/vnd.docker.distribution.manifest.v2+json" -sI --user user:pass https://<registry-origin>/v2/wjs-wealth/manifests/gk-backend:latest
```

Answer (score 2):

I have the same problem. If the a docker image (called **manifest**) pushed to Docker registry v2.0 with **same tag**, new **manifest** will take the tag and the old one will **NOT** deleted instead of existed with no tag assigned.

Such old manifests cannot list from REST API without knowning their digests, and garbage collection will not delete them.

One way I found to get list of manifests of a docker registry repository is via garbage collection tool. Run `docker exec -it registry registry garbage-collect --dry-run /etc/docker/registry/config.yml`. This command will print all manifests (**including those assigned tag**) of all repositories. Such as:

```
hello-world
hello-world: marking manifest sha256:fea8895f450959fa676bcc1df0611ea93823a735a01205fd8622846041d0c7cf
hello-world: marking blob sha256:03f4658f8b782e12230c1783426bd3bacce651ce582a4ffb6fbbfa2079428ecb
hello-world: marking blob sha256:a3ed95caeb02ffe68cdd9fd84406680ae93d633cb16422d00e8a7c22955b46d4
hello-world: marking configuration sha256:690ed74de00f99a7d00a98a5ad855ac4febd66412be132438f9b8dbd300a937d
ubuntu

4 blobs marked, 0 blobs eligible for deletion
```

With **grep** tool, it is easy to filter out **manifest** information only.

Then you can call delete REST API to delete unused manifests. **Take attention not to delete those manifest with tag assigned**.

DELETE REST API only remove manifest information, image data in blob will not delete, so run garbage collection command again without `--dry-run` to remove unused blob: `docker exec -it registry registry garbage-collect /etc/docker/registry/config.yml`

Comment: Thank you for your answer! This part of clean up I already investigated. The only thing for me is left to do is to perform deletion of manifests remotely and automatically to enable GC actually works. As a part of CI.

Answer (score 0):

You need to run this command to get a list of your tags

```
 curl https://<registry>/v2/<repoName>/tags/list
```

Now we want the manifest for each tag - because we don't want to delete it as per [comphilip](https://stackoverflow.com/users/2968044/comphilip)'s answer.

```
curl -H "Accept: application/vnd.docker.distribution.manifest.v2+json" -sI "https://<registry>/v2/<repoName>/manifests/<tag>" | grep "Docker-Content-Digest" | sed 's/Docker-Content-Digest: //;s/\r$//'
```

It is very important to include the header otherwise you get a different Docker-Content-Digest.

This will give you a list of manifests you need to exclude.

Alternatively you can use this method: [docker registry cleanup](https://github.com/mortensteenrasmussen/docker-registry-manifest-cleanup/blob/master/docker-registry-cleanup.sh)

Comment: Unfortunately this url returns me `404 Not Found`. Instead of `curl` I used `wget` like `wget --header="Accept: application/vnd.docker.distribution.manifest.v2+json" --no-check-certificate --http-user=user --http-password=password https://<registry-url>/v2/wjs-wealth/manifests/integration-testing -O-`.

Comment: wget works but curl doesn't?  I've updated the second url in my answer, as the original may have caused confunsion

Comment: Sorry for confusing comment. Please see the question, I updated it due to comment size constraint.

Comment: I meant my answer head confusing content

Comment: Yes, `integration-t‌​esting` is confusing. Originally I didn't guessed that this is the image tag. But anyway if I use right tag I get 404 Not Found