# How to get manifests using HTTP API v2?

Tags: docker-registry

[How to authenticate with the V2 API](https://success.docker.com/article/how-do-i-authenticate-with-the-v2-api) is useful and works.

```sh
REPO="https://hub.docker.com/v2"
```

I'm able to get tokens, list (my) repos and lists their images and tags.

```sh
curl --silent \
--header "Authorization: JWT ${TOKEN}" \
${REPO}/repositories/${USERNAME}/

curl --silent \
--header "Authorization: JWT ${TOKEN}" \
${REPO}/repositories/${USERNAME}/${IMAGE}/tags/
```

I'd like to 'GET MANIFEST' but I'm struggling to get this to work:
https://docs.docker.com/registry/spec/api/#manifest:

```sh
curl --silent \
--header "Host: hub.docker.com" \
--header "Authorization: JWT ${TOKEN}" \
${REPO}/repositories/${USERNAME}/${IMAGE}/manifests/

curl --silent \
--header "Host: hub.docker.com" \
--header "Authorization: JWT ${TOKEN}" \
${REPO}/${USERNAME}/${IMAGE}/manifests/

curl --silent \
--header "Host: hub.docker.com" \
--header "Authorization: JWT ${TOKEN}" \
${REPO}/${USERNAME}/${IMAGE}/manifests/${TAG}
```

I've tried with|without the `Host` header. With various values for the `Host` header. But, I'm clearly missing something. I tried pattern-matching against the working endpoints but no joy:

```
curl --silent \
--header "Authorization: JWT ${TOKEN}" \
${REPO}/repositories/${USERNAME}/${IMAGE}/manifests/
```

Curiously, this page shows "GET TAGS" seemingly incorrectly as `/v2/<name>/tags/list`:
https://docs.docker.com/registry/spec/api/#tags

Reviewed:
https://stackoverflow.com/a/45605443/609290

### Follow-up

I'm a Googler and have access to Google Container Registry (GCR).

```sh
REPO="https://gcr.io/v2/"
```

On a whim, I just tried 'GET MANIFEST' against GCR and the requests works:

```sh
curl --silent \
--request GET \
--user _token:$(gcloud auth print-access-token) \
${REPO}/${PROJECT}/${IMAGE}/manifests/${TAG}
```

Answer (score 5, accepted):

It's quite confusing with all the `*.docker.com|io` subdomains!
I found `registry.hub.docker.com` and `index.docker.io` the most reliable ones.

You can easily query the tags from there, but for the manifests you'll need to get a token for pulling first:

```sh
REGISTRY=https://index.docker.io/v2
#REGISTRY="https://registry.hub.docker.com/v2"
#REGISTRY="https://registry.docker.io/v2"
#REGISTRY="https://registry-1.docker.io/v2"
#REGISTRY="https://hub.docker.com/v2"

REPO=library
IMAGE=debian
# Could also be a repo digest
TAG=latest

# Query tags
curl "$REGISTRY/repositories/$REPO/$IMAGE/tags/"

# Query manifest
curl -iL "$REGISTRY/$REPO/$IMAGE/manifests/$TAG"
# HTTP/1.1 401 Unauthorized
# Www-Authenticate: Bearer realm="https://auth.docker.io/token",service="registry.docker.io",scope="repository:library/debian:pull"

TOKEN=$(curl -sSL "https://auth.docker.io/token?service=registry.docker.io&scope=repository:$REPO/$IMAGE:pull" \
  | jq --raw-output .token)
curl -LH "Authorization: Bearer ${TOKEN}" "$REGISTRY/$REPO/$IMAGE/manifests/$TAG"

# Some repos seem to return V1 Schemas by default

REPO=nginxinc
IMAGE=nginx-unprivileged 
TAG=1.17.2

curl -LH "Authorization: Bearer $(curl -sSL "https://auth.docker.io/token?service=registry.docker.io&scope=repository:$REPO/$IMAGE:pull" | jq --raw-output .token)" \
 "$REGISTRY/$REPO/$IMAGE/manifests/$TAG"

# Solution: Set the Accept Header for V2

curl -LH "Authorization: Bearer $(curl -sSL "https://auth.docker.io/token?service=registry.docker.io&scope=repository:$REPO/$IMAGE:pull" | jq --raw-output .token)" \
  -H "Accept:application/vnd.docker.distribution.manifest.v2+json" \
 "$REGISTRY/$REPO/$IMAGE/manifests/$TAG"
```

See

- [this gist](https://gist.github.com/tnozicka/f46b37f57f7ac755fefa6a0f0c8a77bf) for another example and
- this repo for a reusable script [docker-image-size-curl.sh](https://github.com/schnatterer/docker-image-size/blob/master/scripts/docker-image-size-curl.sh)

Authorization with `hub.docker.com` [works differently](https://success.docker.com/article/how-do-i-authenticate-with-the-v2-api) and you don't seem to get the manifests from there

Comment: You're awesome! Thanks very much for this.

Comment: Your're welcome! I'm also working to put this in a reusable script.
https://github.com/schnatterer/docker-image-size/blob/master/scripts/docker-image-size-curl.sh
Doesn't support the `auth.docker.com`, yet, though.

Comment: `hub.docker.com` works for me. Thanks.