# How to find out the base image for a docker image

Tags: docker

I have a docker image and I would like to find out from which image it has been created. Of course there are multiple layers, but I'd like to find out the last image (the FROM statement in the dockerfile for this image)?

I try to use `docker image history` and `docker image inspect` but I can't find this information in there.

I tried to use the following command but it gives me a error message

```
alias dfimage="sudo docker run -v /var/run/docker.sock:/var/run/docker.sock --rm xyz/mm:9e945ff"
dfimage febae8978318
```

This is the error message I'm getting

```
container_linux.go:235: starting container process caused "exec: \"febae8978318\": executable file not found in $PATH"
/usr/bin/docker-current: Error response from daemon: oci runtime error: container_linux.go:235: starting container process caused "exec: \"febae8978318\": executable file not found in $PATH".
```

Comment: Answer is here: https://stackoverflow.com/a/53841690/3691891

Answer (score 10, accepted):

You can use method suggested in this answer:
https://stackoverflow.com/a/53841690/3691891

First, pull `chenzj/dfimage`:

```
docker pull chenzj/dfimage
```

Get ID of your image:

```
docker images | grep <IMAGE_NAME> | awk '{print $3}'
```

Replace `<IMAGE_NAME>` with the name of your image.  Use this ID as
the parameter to `chenzj/dfimage`:

```
docker run -v /var/run/docker.sock:/var/run/docker.sock --rm chenzj/dfimage <IMAGE_ID>
```

If you find this too hard just pull the `chenzj/dfimage` image and then
use the following `docker-get-dockerfile.sh` script:

```
#!/usr/bin/env sh

if [ "$#" -lt 1 ]
then
    printf "Image name needed\n" >&2
    exit 1
fi

image_id="$(docker images | grep "^$1 " | awk '{print $3}')"
if [ -z "$image_id" ]
then
    printf "Image not found\n" >&2
    exit 2
fi

docker run -v /var/run/docker.sock:/var/run/docker.sock --rm chenzj/dfimage "$image_id"
```

You need to pass image name as the parameter. Example usage:

```
$ ./docker-get-dockerfile.sh alpine
FROM alpine:latest
ADD file:fe64057fbb83dccb960efabbf1cd8777920ef279a7fa8dbca0a8801c651bdf7c in /
CMD ["/bin/sh"]
```

Comment: This displays the image in question as the base image.

Comment: When I did this, it showed the "FROM" as the image that I was trying to find the base of. I don't quite understand - FROM myimage - do lots of stuff - viola you have myimage??

Comment: I'm sure this method used to work back in 2019, something might have changed since then.

Comment: The dfimage image doesn't work at all for me, it just hangs indefinitely

Comment: yeah for me as well it shows the same image is the base image... which is odd

Answer (score 40):

Easy way is to use

```
docker image history deno
```

This above command will give you output like this

[image]

Then just look at the IMAGE column and take that image ID which `a24bb4013296` which is just above the first `<missing>`

Then just do the

For Linux

```
docker image ls | grep a24bb4013296
```

For Windows

```
docker image ls | findstr a24bb4013296
```

This will give you the base image name

[image]

Comment: I think for this to work you need to build the image yourself. At least after docker 1.10 those are intermediate layers you don't get when pulling the image from repository. See https://stackoverflow.com/a/35312577/5519328

Comment: yup I just tried this and it all shows as missing

Comment: As I recall this used to work but no longer does.

Comment: Why I see missing in the IMAGE column, like this:

<missing>      9 months ago

Answer (score 21):

The information doesn't really exist, exactly. An image will contain the layers of its parent(s) but there's no *easy* way to reverse layer digests  back to a `FROM` statement, unless you happen to have (or are able to figure out) the image that contains those layers.

If you have the parent image(s) on-hand (or can find them), you can infer which image(s) your image used for its FROM statement (or ancestry) by cross-referencing the layers.

## Theoretical example

Suppose your image, `FOO`, contains the layers `1 2 3 4 5 6`. If you have another image, `BAR` on your system containing layers `1 2 3`, you could infer that image `BAR` is an ancestor of image `FOO` -- I.E. that `FROM BAR` would have been used at *some point* in its hierarchy.

Suppose further that you have another image, `BAZ` which contains the layers `1 2 3 4 5`. You could infer that image `BAZ` has image `BAR` in its ancestry and that image `FOO` inherits from image `BAZ` (and therefore indirectly from `BAR`).

From this, information you could infer the dockerfiles for these images might have looked something like this:

```
# Dockerfile of image BAR
FROM scratch
# layers 1 2 and 3
COPY ./one /
COPY ./two /
COPY ./three /
```

```
# Dockerfile of Image BAZ
FROM BAR
RUN echo "this makes layer 4" > /four
RUN echo "this makes layer 5" > /five
```

```
# Dockerfile of image FOO
FROM BAZ
RUN echo "this makes layer 6" > /six
```

You could get the exact commands by looking at `docker image history` for each image.

One important thing to keep in mind here, however, is that docker tags are **mutable**; maintainers make new images and move the tags to those images. So if you built an image with `FROM python:3.8.1` today, it won't contain the same layers as if you had built an image with that same `FROM` line a few weeks ago. You'll need the SHA256 digest to be sure you're using the *exact* same image.

## Practical Example, local images

Now that we understand the theory behind identifying images and their bases, let's put it to practice with a real-world example.

Note: because the tags I use will change over time (see above RE: tag mutability), I'll be using the SHA256 digest to pull the images in this example so it can be reproduced by viewers of this answer.

Let's say we have a particular image and we want to find its base(s). We'll use the official `maven` image here.

First, we'll take a look at its layers.

```bash
# maven:3.6-jdk-11-slim at time of writing, on my platform
IMAGE="docker.io/maven@sha256:55f1c145a04e01706233d68fe0b6b20bf76f765ab32f3fe6e29c8ef933917af6"
docker pull $IMAGE
docker image inspect $IMAGE | jq -r '.[].RootFS.Layers[]'
```

This will output the layers:

```
sha256:6e06900bc10223217b4c78081a857866f674c462e4f90593b01894da56df336d
sha256:eda2f4da9b1e70500ac340d40ee039ef3877e8be13b9a24cd345406bf6693412
sha256:6bdb7b3c3e226bdfaa911ba72a95fca13c3979cd150061d570cf569e93037ce6
sha256:ce217e530345060ca0973807a3288560e1e15cf1a4eeec44d6aa594a926c92dc
sha256:f256c980a7d17a00f57fd42a19f6323fcc2341fa46eba128def04824cafa5afa
sha256:446b1af848de2dcb92bbd229ca6ecaabf2f48dab323c19f90d02622e09a8fa67
sha256:10652cf89eaeb5b5d8e0875a6b1867b5cf92c509a9555d3f57d87fab605115a3
sha256:d9a4cf86bf01eb170242ca3b0ce456159fd3fddc9c4d4256208a9d19bae096ca
```

Now, from here, we can try to find other images that have a (strict) subset of these layers. Assuming you *have* the images on-hand, you can find them by cross-referencing the layers of images you have on disk, for example, using `docker image inspect`.

In this case, I just *happen* to know what these images are and have them on-hand (I'll discuss later what you might do if you don't have the images on-hand) so we'll go ahead and pull those images and take a look at the layers.

If you want to follow along:

```bash
# openjdk:11.0.10-jdk-slim at time of writing, on my platform
OPENJDK='docker.io/openjdk@sha256:fe6a46a26ff7d6c31b258e07b3d53f0c42fe68f55f646cc39d60d0b17cbc827b'

# debian:buster-20210329-slim at time of writing on my platform
DEBIAN='docker.io/debian@sha256:088be7d6017ad3ae98325f47707112e1f61687c371be1865e55d5e5531ca97fd'

docker pull $OPENJDK
docker pull $DEBIAN
```

If we inspect these images and compare them against the layers we saw in the output of `docker image inspect` for the `maven` image, we can confirm that the layers from `openjdk` and `debian` are present in our original `maven` image.

```bash
$ docker image inspect $DEBIAN | jq -r '.[].RootFS.Layers[]'
sha256:6e06900bc10223217b4c78081a857866f674c462e4f90593b01894da56df336d

$ docker image inspect $OPENJDK | jq -r '.[].RootFS.Layers[]'
sha256:6e06900bc10223217b4c78081a857866f674c462e4f90593b01894da56df336d
sha256:eda2f4da9b1e70500ac340d40ee039ef3877e8be13b9a24cd345406bf6693412
sha256:6bdb7b3c3e226bdfaa911ba72a95fca13c3979cd150061d570cf569e93037ce6
sha256:ce217e530345060ca0973807a3288560e1e15cf1a4eeec44d6aa594a926c92dc
```

As stated, because these 5 layers are a strict subset of the 8 layers from the maven image, we can conclude the `openjdk` and `debian` images are, at least, both in the ancestry path of the `maven` image.

We can further infer that the last 3 layers most likely come from the `maven` image itself (or, potentially, some unknown image).

## Caveats, when you don't have images locally

Now, of course the above only works because I happen to have all the images on-hand. So, you'd either need to have the images or be able to locate them by the layer digests.

You might still be able to figure this out using information that may be available from registries like Docker Hub or your own private repositories.

For official images, the [docker-library/repo-info](https://github.com/docker-library/repo-info) contains historical information about the official images, including the layer digests for the various tags cataloged over the last several years. You could use this, for example, as a source of layer information.

If you can imagine this like a database of layer digests, you could infer ancestry of at least these official images.

### "Distribution" (remote) digests vs "Content" (local) digests

An important caveat to note is that, when you inspect an image for its layer digests locally, you are getting the *content* digest of the layers. If you are looking at layer digests in a registry manifest (like what appears in the docker-library/repo-info project) you get the compressed *distribution* digest and won't be able to compare the layer digests with content.

So you can compare digests `local <--> local` **OR** `remote <--> remote` only.

### Example, using remote images

Suppose I want to do this same thing, but I want to associate images in a remote repository and find its base(s). We can do the same thing by looking at the layers in the remote manifest.

You can find references how to do this for your particular registry, as described in [this answer for dockerhub](https://stackoverflow.com/a/57878742/5747944).

Using the same images from the example above, we would find that the *distribution* layer digests also match in the same way.

```
$ get-remote-layers $IMAGE
sha256:6fcf2156bc23db75595b822b865fbc962ed6f4521dec8cae509e66742a6a5ad3
sha256:96fde6667c188c81fcddee021ccbb3e054ebe83350fd4609e17a3d37f0ec7f9d
sha256:74d17759dd2a1b51afc740fadd96f655260689a2087308e40d1865a0098c5fae
sha256:bbe8ebb5d0a64d265558901c7c6c66e1d09f664da57cdb2e5f69ba52a7109d31
sha256:b2edaadd7dd62cfe7f551b902244ee67b84bc5c0b6538b9480ac9ca97a0a4986
sha256:0fca65d33e353bdfdd5edd8d4c8ab5efde52c078bd25e2dcf454f995e5420725
sha256:d6d771d0512387eee1e419a965b929a9a3b0365cf1935b3719d60bf9feffcf63
sha256:dee8cd26669373102db07820072127c46bbfdad340a586ee9dfe60ae933eac2b

$ get-remote-layers $DEBIAN
sha256:6fcf2156bc23db75595b822b865fbc962ed6f4521dec8cae509e66742a6a5ad3

$ get-remote-layers $OPENJDK
sha256:6fcf2156bc23db75595b822b865fbc962ed6f4521dec8cae509e66742a6a5ad3
sha256:96fde6667c188c81fcddee021ccbb3e054ebe83350fd4609e17a3d37f0ec7f9d
sha256:74d17759dd2a1b51afc740fadd96f655260689a2087308e40d1865a0098c5fae
sha256:bbe8ebb5d0a64d265558901c7c6c66e1d09f664da57cdb2e5f69ba52a7109d31
```

One other caveat with distribution digests in repositories is that you can only compare digests of the same [manifest schema version](https://docs.docker.com/registry/spec/manifest-v2-2/). So, if an image was pushed with manifest v1 it won't have the same digest pushed again with manifest v2.

## TL;DR

Images contain the layers of their ancestor image(s). Therefore, if an image A contains a strict subset of image B layers, you know that image B is a descendent of image A.

You can use this property of Docker images to determine the base images from which your images were derived.

Comment: Where is get-remote-layers defined?

Comment: @Jason is may be dependent on the registry you use. For Dockerhub, the [linked answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/57878742/5747944) has a working implementation for retrieving the manifest from a remote repo. The layer digests are in the manifest.

Comment: From what I've observed, `Layers` array present in `manifest.json` in a docker tarball always have the last layer from base image missing in the child image.

Answer (score -3):

```
docker run image:tag cat /etc/*release*
```

Run a docker container from that image with the command above(change "image:tag" with your image name and tag). your container will print details you need to answer your question.