# How to know which base OS is used in httpd:latest image of apache

Tags: docker

How to know which base OS is used in httpd (latest version)  image of apache.

Thanks in advance for reply.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [How to find out the base image for a docker image](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/58018422/how-to-find-out-the-base-image-for-a-docker-image)

Comment: You can also look for various marker files in `/etc` in the container filesystem.  This doesn't really seem like a programming-related question, though.

Answer (score 0):

It's based on `debian:buster-slim`

Some docker-images on dockerhub supply links to Dockerfile-sources:

- https://hub.docker.com/_/httpd
- https://github.com/docker-library/httpd/blob/master/2.4/Dockerfile

Alternatively start a container from image and run `cat /etc/*release`

Comment: How did you find the link https://github.com/docker-library/httpd/blob/master/2.4/Dockerfile. Also, what is the way to know the base OS of other images like nginx, tomcat etc. So, my question is generic, i want to know is there any standard process laid down to know the base OS used in different images.

Comment: go to https://hub.docker.com/_/httpd and look for anything that hints at where the source of the Dockerfile could be hosted (usually github). Finding out the the OS of the image can always be done from inside the running container (see `cat /etc/*release`