# Does the FROM command create a layer and how to check number of layers?

Tags: docker, dockerfile, docker-layer

I am reading the [official Docker docs](https://docs.docker.com/storage/storagedriver/#images-and-layers), and it is unclear to me how many layers will be created for the below dockerfile.

```
# syntax=docker/dockerfile:1
FROM ubuntu:18.04
LABEL org.opencontainers.image.authors="org@example.com"
COPY . /app
RUN make /app
RUN rm -r $HOME/.cache
CMD python /app/app.py
```

As per my understanding, four layers will be created - first from FROM command, then COPY command, and then two layers from each RUN command.

I have another question: **how many layers does the FROM command create? Does it create only one layer, or can it create more than one layer?**

Comment: I think it would be 3 layers plus how many layers are in `ubuntu:18.04`

Comment: FROM will only create one ("container") layer, but if your Docker engine doesn't have the base image, it will have to pull and build it first. https://jessicagreben.medium.com/digging-into-docker-layers-c22f948ed612 https://stackoverflow.com/a/67927907/2125723

Comment: @ryanwebjackson, FROM certainly doesn't create container layer. Container layer will be created at runtime.

Comment: @hagrawal7777 was I able to resolve your doubts?

Comment: Hi @Paolo, you were really helpful in understanding this, thank you. I have already done +1 but I cannot accept the answer right now as I am looking for a step-by-step proof (for myself as well as for future visitors) how anyone can checks the layers. I will try if I can put a answer, otherwise I will accept your answer.

Answer (score 1):

The key concept is:

> Commands that modify the filesystem create a layer.

so in your example, the `COPY` command and the `RUN` commands will create one layer each (so 3 in total).

These layers are added to whatever layers the base image has.

---

```bash
$ docker inspect ubuntu:18.04 | jq '.[].RootFS.Layers'
[
   "sha256:b7e0fa7bfe7f9796f1268cca2e65a8bfb1e010277652cee9a9c9d077a83db3c4"
]
```

given:

```
FROM ubuntu:18.04
RUN echo hello
RUN echo world
ADD foo .
```

then:

```bash
$ docker build -t foo . 2>/dev/null && docker inspect foo | jq '.[].RootFS.Layers'
[
  "sha256:b7e0fa7bfe7f9796f1268cca2e65a8bfb1e010277652cee9a9c9d077a83db3c4",
  "sha256:5f70bf18a086007016e948b04aed3b82103a36bea41755b6cddfaf10ace3c6ef",
  "sha256:5f70bf18a086007016e948b04aed3b82103a36bea41755b6cddfaf10ace3c6ef",
  "sha256:b422bf2b9916188c7df60fc54a82b9496b0d4c228b0f602e1e0f028a3acdeced"
]
```

so you end up with whatever layers you had in the base image, plus the new layers. `FROM` in itself does not create a layer.

Comment: @hagrawal7777 not sure if you saw my comments, but the layer `"sha256:b7e0fa7bfe7f9796f1268cca2e65a8bfb1e010277652cee9a9c9d077a83db3c4"` is the layer of the base image, it is not generated by the `FROM` statement

Answer (score 1):

It will create 4 layers. According to the docker documentation:-

[image]

[image]

1. The **FROM** command will create a new Layer.
2. The **COPY** command add files so it will update the filesystem. So, it will create a  new layer.
3. The first **RUN** command builds your application and writes the result to a new layer.
4. Lastly the second **RUN** command remove the directory. So, it will create a new layer.

Some are saying that, FROM doesn't create a layer. So, for them, I am sharing documentation part. Please Look:-

[image]

Comment: **Comments have been [moved to chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/253564/discussion-on-answer-by-developer-how-many-layers-will-get-created-especially-b); please do not continue the discussion here.** Before posting a comment below this one, please review the [purposes of comments](/help/privileges/comment). Comments that do not request clarification or suggest improvements usually belong as an [answer](/help/how-to-answer), on [meta], or in [chat]. Comments continuing discussion may be removed.

Answer (score 0):

Below is the [quote from official documentation](https://docs.docker.com/storage/storagedriver/#images-and-layers). Going by the official documentation it is clear that there will be four layers. Also, the answer from other member proves that there will be four layers.

> This Dockerfile contains four commands. Commands that modify the
> filesystem create a layer. **The FROM statement starts out by creating a
> layer from the ubuntu:18.04 image.** The LABEL command only modifies the
> image’s metadata, and does not produce a new layer. **The COPY command
> adds some files from your Docker client’s current directory. The first
> RUN command builds your application using the make command, and writes
> the result to a new layer. The second RUN command removes a cache
> directory, and writes the result to a new layer.** Finally, the CMD
> instruction specifies what command to run within the container, which
> only modifies the image’s metadata, which does not produce an image
> layer.

Answer (score 0):

The layers are inherited from the base image, whatever that image contains will be the starting point for your new image.

Those saying that your example will result in 4 layers are correct because ubuntu only has one layer to start with, not because the FROM line is repackaged into a single layer.

```
$ docker inspect ubuntu:latest --format '{{json .RootFS.Layers}}' | jq .
[
  "sha256:b8a36d10656ac19ddb96ef3107f76820663717708fc37ce929925c36d1b1d157"
]
```

Lets take a better example, nginx contains several layers:

```bash
$ cat df.layers
FROM nginx:latest
RUN echo "hello" >/hello.txt
CMD [ "ls", "-l", "/" ]

$ docker build -t test-layers -f df.layers .
[+] Building 0.9s (6/6) FINISHED
 => [internal] load build definition from df.layers                                                0.0s
 => => transferring dockerfile: 107B                                                               0.0s
 => [internal] load .dockerignore                                                                  0.0s
 => => transferring context: 49B                                                                   0.0s
 => [internal] load metadata for docker.io/library/nginx:latest                                    0.0s
 => [1/2] FROM docker.io/library/nginx:latest                                                      0.1s
 => [2/2] RUN echo "hello" >/hello.txt                                                             0.7s
 => exporting to image                                                                             0.0s
 => => exporting layers                                                                            0.0s
 => => writing image sha256:3bc381601cdb33e4159ac4ee7e3e5724dbd47b01e37c24f2aac0dc1fbd40131e       0.0s
 => => naming to docker.io/library/test-layers                                                     0.0s
```

Next, lets compare the resulting layers in each of those images:

```bash
$ docker inspect nginx:latest --format '{{json .RootFS.Layers}}' | jq .
[
  "sha256:8553b91047dad45bedc292812586f1621e0a464a09a7a7c2ce6ac5f8ba2535d7",
  "sha256:a29cc9587af6488ae0cbb962ecbe023d347908cc62ca5d715af06e54ccaa9e36",
  "sha256:6bc8ae8fb3cf0909b3d9c2e74f6cabe16e6a2322c52cec76fbaecaef47006f1d",
  "sha256:5684be535bf11cb9ad1a57b51085f36d84ae8361eabc2b4c2ba9a83e8b084b20",
  "sha256:93ee76f39c974e4f819e632149c002d6f509aadc5995ec6523a96b337751c8ed",
  "sha256:1040838fe30e6f26d31bde96c514f47ee4bf727b3f1c3c7b045ea3891c1c2150"
]

$ docker inspect test-layers:latest --format '{{json .RootFS.Layers}}' | jq .
[
  "sha256:8553b91047dad45bedc292812586f1621e0a464a09a7a7c2ce6ac5f8ba2535d7",
  "sha256:a29cc9587af6488ae0cbb962ecbe023d347908cc62ca5d715af06e54ccaa9e36",
  "sha256:6bc8ae8fb3cf0909b3d9c2e74f6cabe16e6a2322c52cec76fbaecaef47006f1d",
  "sha256:5684be535bf11cb9ad1a57b51085f36d84ae8361eabc2b4c2ba9a83e8b084b20",
  "sha256:93ee76f39c974e4f819e632149c002d6f509aadc5995ec6523a96b337751c8ed",
  "sha256:1040838fe30e6f26d31bde96c514f47ee4bf727b3f1c3c7b045ea3891c1c2150",
  "sha256:6994e46eed98d24824300283a52d7e6c905936c688366c51a77ab27c2f7b80e4"
]
```

The first 6 layers are identical, then the RUN in the Dockerfile added a single new layer. These layers are shared since they are part of a content addressable store, it's a hash of the tar+gz of the filesystem changes. They don't get repacked into a single layer which would result in more space to store and bandwidth to distribute.

You can also see the steps in the history of the image, not every step creates a layer, and docker shows these in reverse chronological order:

```bash
$ docker history test-layers
IMAGE          CREATED         CREATED BY                                      SIZE      COMMENT
3bc381601cdb   2 minutes ago   CMD ["ls" "-l" "/"]                             0B        buildkit.dockerfile.v0
<missing>      2 minutes ago   RUN /bin/sh -c echo "hello" >/hello.txt # bu…   6B        buildkit.dockerfile.v0
<missing>      5 days ago      /bin/sh -c #(nop)  CMD ["nginx" "-g" "daemon…   0B
<missing>      5 days ago      /bin/sh -c #(nop)  STOPSIGNAL SIGQUIT           0B
<missing>      5 days ago      /bin/sh -c #(nop)  EXPOSE 80                    0B
<missing>      5 days ago      /bin/sh -c #(nop)  ENTRYPOINT ["/docker-entr…   0B
<missing>      5 days ago      /bin/sh -c #(nop) COPY file:e57eef017a414ca7…   4.62kB
<missing>      5 days ago      /bin/sh -c #(nop) COPY file:abbcbf84dc17ee44…   1.27kB
<missing>      5 days ago      /bin/sh -c #(nop) COPY file:5c18272734349488…   2.12kB
<missing>      5 days ago      /bin/sh -c #(nop) COPY file:7b307b62e82255f0…   1.62kB
<missing>      5 days ago      /bin/sh -c set -x     && addgroup --system -…   61.6MB
<missing>      5 days ago      /bin/sh -c #(nop)  ENV PKG_RELEASE=1~bullseye   0B
<missing>      5 days ago      /bin/sh -c #(nop)  ENV NJS_VERSION=0.7.11       0B
<missing>      5 days ago      /bin/sh -c #(nop)  ENV NGINX_VERSION=1.23.4     0B
<missing>      5 days ago      /bin/sh -c #(nop)  LABEL maintainer=NGINX Do…   0B
<missing>      5 days ago      /bin/sh -c #(nop)  CMD ["bash"]                 0B
<missing>      5 days ago      /bin/sh -c #(nop) ADD file:a2378c1b12e95db69…   80.5MB
```