# How to find the actual tag of a "latest" Docker image in Docker hub, starting from a container image built months ago

Tags: python, docker, dockerfile

I have a local Docker image built months ago, using a Dockerfile starting with `FROM python`

Now that image is still in a server that I can access, and I need to create a new Dockefile to generate a container starting from EXACTLY THE SAME python image used when the image was originally build.

If I use `FROM python` in my new Dockerfile, I will get a different python version, and a different OS within the new container. Instead, I would like to understand which python tag corresponds to the "latest" tag used months ago to originally build that image.

How can I do that?

Comment: Does this answer your question? [How to find out the base image for a docker image](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/58018422/how-to-find-out-the-base-image-for-a-docker-image)

Comment: To restrict the search in this specific case you could try:  `docker run -it --rm image-name python --version && cat /etc/os-release` to get the version of Python and of the OS.